# C# DotNetZip : AddEntry Open/Close Delegate - Using open delegate more than once (Zip files)

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

The below code shows using the open/close delegate. The stream that is returned is a non-seekable stream and can only be read once, but it seems like it is trying to read the stream more than once. Anyone know why?

This seems to only happen when the file i'm adding is a zip file.

```
zipFile.AddEntry
    (
        pair.Key, 
        (entryName) => pair.Value.LoadFile(),
        (entryName, stream) =>
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    );
```